# Mediawiki: ""There is currently no text in this page." displayed in pages listed in Lists of pages and these pages are not editable

Tags: mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki powered website. I am able to see the links to all the pages from Special pages -> Lists of pages. But if I click a link to the page listed there, the page with that page name only has the following content:

"There is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, search the related logs, or **edit this page**."

Then, if I click **edit this page**, I get the following content in the editing page:

"**Cannot find section**
You tried to edit a section that does not exist. It may have been moved or deleted while you were viewing the page."

And I checked the database and found that all those pages do have texts.

How can I get all the page texts displayed and editable. Thanks

Comment: Could you share a URL for your wiki so that we can see this?  It seems strange.

Comment: It turns out that the latest revision that the page associates with does not have corresponding text in the text table. To solve this problem, I created corresponding empty text row in the text table, and then the page is editable again. As for the content of those pages, I searched database and I believe those contents have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the latest revision that the page associates with does not have corresponding text in the text table. To solve this problem, I created corresponding empty text row in the text table, and then the page is editable again. As for the content of those pages, I searched database and I believe those contents have been lost.